# Can I digitalize a dictionary?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, computer-vision, ocr

I've found a public domain latin<->portuguese dictionary in PDF which I'd like to convert to plain text, parse and use as the database of a program. After some testing, however, I got a little skeptical. Take a look at the [original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynNq4.png) and at the [resulting text of gocr](http://dabc50b2975da0ae.paste.se/). Is there any hope that I might reach 99%+ accuracy in some method? I thought of reCaptcha's database, but I guess it is Google's property, isn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: The dictionary itself has low quality characters. You will have to perform serious training, and even then, you will have to go through it for corrections. According to this article (http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison), tesseract might better suit you. Though a cleaner scan is preferred above all.

Comment: Is there any reason you'd like to scan this dictionary, rather than just using an existing resource like WordNet?

Comment: Because it's a Latin<->Portuguese dictionary, not an english one!

Comment: The output of tesseract, although still not perfect, is indeed much better! http://500f31248c1dd135.paste.se/

Answer (score 2):

Another route is to use one of the freely available dictionary files, like http://www.brothersoft.com/downloads/dictionary-database.html

Answer (score 2):

Or [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

EDIT: I've just spotted that this is a Latin/Portuguese dictionary, so WordNet clearly is no good.